# flat file sql needed (old data concepts )

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I need to get that email address. The definition of this Physical File is: I have a crystal report that is going to have the sales rep id name (DMARANO1). I need to get the email address of the rep so the report can send to him/her only on correct rep data.

```
1-4 CAT
5-20 REF FILE SELECTION
21-22 RFSQ2
23-62 RDATA
63-63 FILLER 
64-64 ACTIVITY CODE
```

As I see it, the 0025 has the sales rep name and code (code =  DM1), then the 8757 has that code DM1 and the email.
I need to read the 0025, get the code, on the '01' record,  then read the 8757
I would have the DMARANO1 to match on (the 0075 record.)
this is not ideal way but we are using a very old Iseries code here.

```
0025DM1             01DEMI MARANO                      0000000 + 
0025DM1             02000000                                   +   
0075DMARANO1        01                                         +   
0075DMARANO1        02                                      00 +   
0075DMARANO1        0311OACI        11 1                       +   
0075DMARANO1        05            0                            +   
0075DOLDHOFF        01                                         +   
0075DOLDHOFF        02                                      00 +   
0075DOLDHOFF        0311OACI         11 1                      +   
0075DOLDHOFF        05            0                            +   
8511DS55            010030210210004000000002500000030000000000 +   
8511DS55            02000000023400006250001750PLSSDM55  GOLD   +   
8506DMARANO1        01CUS1                                     +   
0069DS55            01ENG-1.75"X.625" GOLD FLEXI    7000       +   
7012DMARANO1        01                                         +   
8757DM1             01DMARANO@TESTAWARDS.COM                  +   
8757DM1             02914-347-7566452DEMI MORANO               
8511GNPY            010110180180004000000002500000110000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the physical file is named **FILE**, it contains a single 64 character field named **FILE**, and the records can be joined on **REF_FILE_SELECTION** and **RFSQ2** the following SQL should get you started:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
    SUBSTR(FILE, 1, 4) CAT,
    SUBSTR(FILE, 5, 15) REF_FILE_SELECTION,
    SUBSTR(FILE, 21, 2) RFSQ2,
    SUBSTR(FILE, 23, 40) RDATA,
    SUBSTR(FILE, 63, 1) FILLER,
    SUBSTR(FILE, 64, 1) ACTIVITY_CODE
FROM FILE)
SELECT A.REF_FILE_SELECTION, B.RDATA
FROM CTE A
JOIN CTE B ON A.REF_FILE_SELECTION = B.REF_FILE_SELECTION AND A.RFSQ2 = B.RFSQ2
WHERE A.CAT='0025' AND A.RFSQ2='01' AND B.CAT='8757'
```

[image: Results]